# How can I work with big numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I'm solving Project Euler problems and when I want to iterate over very large numbers, with more than 10 digits, CodeSkulptor, the IDE I work with, gets stuck. How could I, using Python, operate with big numbers? A different IDE, perhaps?

Comment: What? Your IDE shouldn't influence anything.

Comment: Zizouz212 - CodeSkulptor is an online Python interpreter written in JavaScript, for Rice University's Python courses both onsite and on Coursera. On one hand this avoids problems by ensuring that all students are using the same environment and not having any problems installing things on their own systems, but on the other hand it's only a subset of Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have fond memories of CodeSkulptor from the Rice University Python courses on Coursera, but for general Python use outside of those courses I would recommend a full-featured IDE like JetBrains' free community edition of PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

If you look at the CodeSkulptor documentation -- http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#tabs-Python -- it says that it only implements "a subset of Python 2", so yes, for Project Euler and other non-Rice/Coursera projects, use PyCharm or another full-featured IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Python can handle numbers as large as your memory will allow. Python will automatically convert `int` to `long` when it reaches `sys.maxint`:

```
In [28]: print type(sys.maxint+0)
<type 'int'>

In [29]: print type(sys.maxint+1)
<type 'long'>

In [30]: print 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 + 2;
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111113
```

So this very well might be an IDE problem. Try running your code in [iPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/), or use a standard text editor and the `python` binary, and make sure it works properly. If it does, then your IDE is probably to blame!

I have generally had good luck with PyCharm (there is a free version), but I often just use Sublime Text (which is more of a "smart editor" than an IDE, but gets the job done).

Comment: Ok, so I've already installed Python 3.5.1 and Sublime Text. How can I use Python with Sublime Text? Have I got to import anything?@Will

Comment: @IgnasiSegura You write your code in sublime text, save it as something like "my_script.py" and then you execute it in your terminal like this: `python my_script.py`.